# Eclipse/MapReduce plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, hadoop, mapreduce

I've been searching for a MapReduce plugin for eclipse, but most of them didn't work for me. The only one that did work had the old API's template when creating Mappers/Reducers/Drivers.

So I thought I'll compile one myself, which unfortunately uses the same "old API" as the default template which gives errors. Even with the newest alpha and beta (2.0.3 and 2.0.4) versions of Hadoop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working.  I've changed the source of `$HADOOP_HOME/src/contrib/eclipse_plugin` and then compiled it with Hadoop 1.2.0. I thought I'd share it but didn't know where. The only place that came to my mind was StackOverflow, so sorry if this isn't the place.

So here it is, Hadoop Eclipse Plugin with the new API template:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y990pp610t3edfo/hadoop-eclipse-plugin-1.2.0-newapi.jar

If someone wants to compile it himself I'll post the source codes too, which are only 3 more *.java files. Just ask.

Comment: This works great for me. I can now connect to my hadoop instance from eclipse. However, when I try to run a MapReduce project it does not let me select my hadoop instance. I have seen this in earlier versions of the plugin not being campatable with certain eclipse versions. What version of eclipse are you using? (I'm on Kepler)

Comment: I was only able to get this to work on eclipse juno once I specified the hdfs paths as the guy did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133082/hadoop-wordcount-example-run-on-hadoopeclipse-option-is-not-prompting-select `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, "hdfs://localhost:54310/home/hduser1/gutenbergIP/pg4300.txt");` Is there a way to fix the real problem?

Comment: I'm using "eclipse juno" as well, never tried it on other versions. Anyway, there have been some changes in the API. The new API is called MapReduce New API. Here is a link to a short slide which shows how to upgrade to the new API: http://www.slideshare.net/sh1mmer/upgrading-to-the-new-map-reduce-api

Comment: Here are a couple of projects I wrote for my app so you can compare your script to these. This zip file includes `Finding Mutual Friends` between two users and `Recommending Friends` to a user (Something like People you may know from Facebook).  Unfortunately, I didn't use any commenting so if you don't understand something you can always ask. I'll be glad to help as much as I can.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uk6phmne0jjuda2/MapRed%20Examples.zip

Comment: For the path you'll have to use `FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/path/to/gutenberg/book.txt"));`